# Has any culture primarily worshipped an evil deity?

Tags: religion, cultural-history

I was recently re-watching the *Star Trek: The Next Generation* episode [Masks](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Masks_(episode)), (because I'm not a nerd even a little bit), and an interesting thought struck me: the culture portrayed in that episode seems to have had a pantheon centered around an incredibly cruel, if not outright evil, torturer-Queen deity named Masaka.  The other gods from her pantheon seem to either be hiding from her, fearing her, or trying to counter her influence.  This is not unlike the episode [Devil's Due](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Devil's_Due_(episode)), in which another society seems to hold the negative deity, a devil-figure named Ardra, above all others.

It made me wonder, have any historical cultures revered a negative or evil deity as their primary or most-powerful figure?  Obviously plenty of primary deities (such as Zeus or Odin or even the Old Testament Yahweh) have been shown to be cruel, callous, or capricious at times, but these gods are also heavily tied to ideas like justice, courage, or mercy.  They are, ultimately, positive forces in the universe and toward humanity.

Have any societies held a strictly evil or malevolent deity above all others?

**EDIT:** In response to several commenters, I thought I'd clarify: I'm talking about gods whose *own worshippers* considered the god a force of evil, not those who are interpreted as such by outsiders, and certainly not a discussion of whether religion itself is positive.  I'm saying that Zeus, Odin, and the Judeochristian God are all viewed by their followers as "good."  Were any pantheon-topping gods seen by their own worshippers as primarily malevolent, rather than benevolent?

Comment: That depends on interpretation. What has been often portrayed by colonial masters as evil has in the reassessment of history been shown otherwise. The distinguishing lines are blurry and the debates incredibly unending.

Comment: Whether the judaeochristian god is "positive forces in the universe" is a matter of opinion and shifting morality standards

Comment: Surely some culture guessed the evil gods were more powerful than the good gods.

Comment: From a certain point of view, all of the world's major organized religions are evil in that they turn humanity against itself.

Comment: In response to Rajib, user5001, and CGCampbell: check out the edit I just made for clarification.  Close-voters: may I ask why?  It's a fairly simple question about historical mythology and culture.

Comment: While the question is more hard to answer now, I guess the reason is in general the human tendency is to worship goodness/virtue rather than evil. Voted retraction, because I realize my argument is social, not historical.

Comment: Generally speaking, any controlling deity would be good as they would be setting the definition of what is good. This leaves it rather unanswerable as you get into questions about what constitutes 'good'.

Comment: @pluckedkiwi That's a true of most monotheistic religions, where "God" is usually the ultimate standard of goodness and righteousness, but plenty of (maybe all?) polytheistic religions have flawed deities who can be greedy, untrustworthy, or cruel. In this question, I'm looking for evil (in the case of the former) or actively malevolent toward humanity (in the case of the latter). As just one example, did any cultures worship an "oppressor god" who will one day be vanquished by the return of a long-absent god of righteousness?

Comment: Take to theology.  There is no aspect of time here.

Comment: @SamuelRussell  It's a question about historical cultures. Questions about historical cultures aren't suitable for a historical site?

Comment: The question should be limited to cultures using human sacrifice. That's as evil as it goes. Druids, Romans, Mongols, Maya, etc.

Comment: @DeerHunter  I think you misunderstood the question.  I wasn't asking about "evil religions," I was asking about religions focused on a deity that the worshippers themselves consider evil.  The cultures you mentioned performed human sacrifices, but they were in service to a god that the worshippers considered good.

Answer (score 3):

This is kind of tough to answer, as few people look upon themselves as "evil", and there are adherents to pretty much every religion that will happily tell you everyone else is worshiping devils.

That being said, the best candidate I can think of is the [Thuggee](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thuggee) (Thugs). Yes, we got the word from a historical people. This was a society in India that believed they were descended from [Kali](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kali) (Hindu goddess of death), and made their living by murdering travelers and caravans. Its debatable how religious they actually were though. There are millions of modern-day Kali worshipers who would quite strenuously object to any insinuation that Kali is an "evil" goddess.

Comment: the thuggee idea has been re-assessed and post-colonial history says this was a construction by the British to enable them to criminalize resistance. In other words, its debatable. In any case even if they were "evil", the idea of Kali herself being evil has long been rejected- as you pointed out.

Comment: @Rajib - That's the revisionist position. It is [not universally accepted](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thuggee#21st_century_revisionist_views), the chief problem with it being the extensive documentation of the group that would have to be explained away. A better critique is that the relation to Kali was probably at best a foundation myth for the group. Most of the captured Thugs turned out to be Muslim, not Hindu. This was probably more in the nature of a biker gang calling themselves the "Hell's Angels".

Comment: yes as I said, it's debatable, like all post-colonial thought. So yes- agreed.